# For the life of me I cant get the input to accept anything in the Game Of Darts tutorial for adding stuff to the dom

Tags: html, input, dart

I have been researching for a while, At first my own code would not work so I tried the one provided and still when I try to enter a item into the list, nothing happens. No text is added or deleted and it is like the enter key does nothing. I found similar problems but nothing using dart.

Comment: Just noticed this pops up                                                             Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://127.0.0.1:3030/C:/Users/Fruni/dart/app/web/packages/browser/dart.js

Comment: Are you using the Dart Editor?  If not, you'll need to run `pub install` from wherever the `pubspec.yaml` file is.

Comment: Yes I am, ran it in dart as well. No avail.

Comment: Browser dependency needed to be updated... QQ Works now.

Comment: You mean you needed to do a pub update?  Can you submit that as the formal answer to this question. If someone else has the same problem, they are more likely to discover the solution if it is in the answer than if it is in a comment.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Browser dependency needed to be updated... QQ Works now